# Concat mutiple SQL scalar-valued function values

Tags: sql

I have defined the following scalar-valued function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION getName
(
    @name NVARCHAR(200),
    @deletedDate DATETIME2(7) = NULL,
    @suffix NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN QUOTENAME(CONCAT(@name, IIF(@suffix IS NOT NULL, ' ' + @suffix, ''), IIF(@deletedDate IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' (DELETED - ', FORMAT(@deletedDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'), ')'), '')))
END
```

And what I'm trying to do is to concatenate its results in a variable as follows:

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + [dbo].[getName]([Name], [DeletedDate], DEFAULT)
FROM [dbo].[Items]
WHERE [ProjectId] = 1
ORDER BY [Order] DESC;

SELECT @Columns
```

But the `@Columns` result only has the last result of the function and if I remove the function and do inline computation it works as expected (having all the values).

I can't understand why is this not working when using the function.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using MS-SQL (Azure SQL Database)

Answer (score 1):

Because I couldn't find any answer on the internet, If anyone else needs the answer, I've managed to resolve it with an intermediary CTE:

```
WITH Names_CTE
AS 
(
    SELECT   [dbo].[getName]([Name], [DeletedDate], DEFAULT) AS [Name], [Order]
    FROM     [dbo].[ITems]
    WHERE    [ProjectId] = 1
    ORDER BY [Order] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + [Name]
FROM Names_CTE

SELECT @Columns
```

I think that was not working because we needed to know the values up front to perform the computation together with `COALESCE`.